# Content Delivery Cluster- Load Balancer Session configuration

Tags: configuration, session-state, load-balancer

My client needs to change from "Single CD and Separate CM" to "clustered CD and separate CM" with Load balancer for CD cluster.

Sitecore version: 8.1 (rev. 160519), In this [sitecore document](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/session_state/session_state_configuration_scenarios) it mentioned,

- With Sticky LB : ASP.NET session state provider use InProc, sharedsession use OutProc
- With non-sticky LB : use outproc for both private and shared.

In another [document](http://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/xDB/xdb-architecture/xdb-session-state/), It mentioned like this

> As soon as you scale to multiple CDs within a cluster, you must use
>   OutProc session management for both private and shared session data

and also says not to mix inproc and outproc

> Theoretically possible, but not recommended. You are getting the worst
>   of both worlds in terms of reduced speed (OutProc) and reduced
>   reliability (InProc).

Now I'm bit confused, if I use LB with sticky session enabled for CD cluster should I mix InProc and OutProc as mentioned  in the first document or Should I only use OutProc?

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider two statements about LB and sessions:

1. Sticky LB will route user to same CD server in cluster.
2. OutProc session is required to share session information between
   servers.

Knowing this, you can make conclusion that with sticky LB it is possible to use both OutProc and InProc session states. But usage of OutProc will be a little bit excessive. So, you can use any: either OutProc or InProc.